# SQL Server: Comparing Concatenated Columns for Equality of Unordered Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, concatenation, equality

I have two tables with an ID column (that matches the tables together) and concatenated columns where the concatenated values are in an arbitrary order. I want to compare to see if the two columns contain the exact same items (in any order) and output the ID if they don't.

Example:

Table 1

```
PersonID    Products
1           Apple|Pear|Orange
2           Flour|Apple|Butter
3           Apple
4           Banana|Cashews
5           Juice|Crackers|Banana|Cashews
6           Cashews
```

Table 2

```
PersonID    Products
1           Orange|Apple|Pear
2           Flour|Apple|Butter
3           Apple|Banana
4           Banana
5           Crackers|Juice|Banana|Cashews
6           Pear|Crackers
```

I would like to get all the personids where products are not an identical set (any order) between table 1 and table 2. So in this case that is:
Person 3 (extra product), person 4 (missing product) and person 6 (different products).

My current query is erroneously picking up Persons 1 and 5 because they have products ordered differently.

My current query is like this:

```
select t1.personid, t1.products as t1products, t2.products as t2products
from table1 t1 (nolock)
inner join table2 t2 (nolock) on t1.personid = t2.personid
where t1.products != t2.products
```

I also have the data in pre-concatenation form, with multiple rows per personid (one for each product, and again separately in two tables), if that is more helpful - I haven't figured out how to concatenate them in alphabetical order, so a solution to that effect would also solve this problem.

Edit (clarification):
The unconcatenated data looks like the following:

Table 1

```
PersonID    Product
1           Apple
1           Pear
1           Orange
2           Flour
2           Apple
2           Butter
3           Apple
```

etc.

Table 2

```
PersonID    Product
1           Orange
1           Apple
1           Pear
2           Flour
2           Apple
2           Butter
3           Apple
3           Banana
```

etc.

I used STUFF to concatenate them by PersonID.

Comment: How many columns of products are there that need to be alphabetized if you were to go that route?  That would be as simple as some nested `CASE` statements with `>` or `<` operators if there are only a few columns.

Comment: The structure is multiple rows for products, not columns (so jobid is repeated on multiple rows). They can go anywhere from 1 - 300, most commonly around 5-10 rows each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have it in the form of one product for each row then you can query for all the results that don't have a match for both product and personid in the opposite table. Then do the same for the other table and union the results:

```
SELECT t1.personid, t1.product, '2' AS [Not Found In Table]
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.personid = t2.personid AND t1.product = t2.product
WHERE t2.product IS NULL
UNION
SELECT t2.personid, t2.product,  '1' AS [Not Found In Table]
FROM table2 t2 
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.personid = t1.personid AND t2.product = t1.product
WHERE t1.product IS NULL
```

You could wrap this in a select and `CONCAT` the results to feed you a nice list of what is missing from which table for each person who doesn't match.

Comment: This solution does take the order of the products into consideration. hence two person ids with exactly the same product but in a different order will showup in the result set/

Comment: [Bad habits: putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

Comment: I agree with the no lock comment bacon , but I don't know what reason he had for having them in his original query.

Comment: @M.Ali, if this query were running against the concatenated results it would take order into consideration, but as the answer stated, this was intended to be run against the tables that have one product per row, and multiple rows for persons with multiple related products.  Because these are separated out, there is no concern about the order.

Answer (score 3):

**Test Data**

```
Declare @t1 TABLE (PersonID INT, Products Varchar(200))
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES
(1   ,'Apple|Pear|Orange'),
(2   ,'Flour|Apple|Butter'),
(3   ,'Apple'),
(4   ,'Banana|Cashews'),
(5   ,'Juice|Crackers|Banana|Cashews'),
(6   ,'Cashews');

Declare @t2 TABLE (PersonID INT, Products Varchar(200))
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES
(1   ,'Orange|Apple|Pear'),
(2   ,'Flour|Apple|Butter'),
(3   ,'Apple|Banana'),
(4   ,'Banana'),
(5   ,'Crackers|Juice|Banana|Cashews'),
(6   ,'Pear|Crackers');
```

**Query**

```
WITH Table1 AS (
SELECT  PersonID
        ,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Products
FROM   
    (SELECT PersonID
            ,Cast ('<X>' + Replace(Products, '|', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
    FROM    @t1
    ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
), Table2 AS (
SELECT  PersonID
        ,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Products
FROM   
    (SELECT PersonID
            ,Cast ('<X>' + Replace(Products, '|', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
    FROM    @t2
    ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
)
SELECT t1.PersonID 
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID 
                  AND t1.Products = t2.Products)
UNION  
SELECT t2.PersonID 
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID 
                  AND t1.Products = t2.Products)
```

Comment: That is about how I was imagining it before I read the part about having the data already separated into rows.  I am glad that someone did the difficult version:)

Answer (score 1):

I am simply pairing up the rows on full join. in this way, if pair appears this means product matches and if not, that means there's a problem.
So I hope this simple query can also solve your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM table2
) d 
GROUP BY PersonID, Products 
HAVING COUNT(*) != 2
```